# VB - Put multiple items from ListBox to textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, windows-forms-designer

I need insert multiple selected items from ListBox to TextBox and if I deselect some item, it will be deleted from the text box.

**Example**:

1. Name1 - selected
2. Name2
3. Name3 - selected

**Result**:

TextBox: Name1, Name3

My code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Name As String = ListBox1.SelectedItems.ToString
    TextBox3.Text = Name + ", "
End Sub
```

But when I select an item, so it will insert into the textbox this "*System.Windows.Forms.ListBox*" Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far. You can't just expect people here to do your work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I already updated this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
      TextBox3.Text = ""
      For Each Name In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        TextBox3.Text += Name + ", "
      Next
End Sub
```

name might have the text proprety in it
try `Name.text` or `Name.Caption` i don't remember very well

Answer (score 0):

ListBox.SelectedItems is collection. You have iterate throw it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Try this (c# syntax):

```
var names = string.Join(",",ListBox1.SelectedItems.Select(x=>x.ToString())
```